# C#, XNA Arrows should only be visible in a rectangle

Tags: c#, xna

I created a red rectangle with yellow arrows in it. The arrows are always moving upwards and every arrow has the same speed. If an arrow is out of the rectangle(crosses the upper edge of the rectangle), then a new arrow should enter the rectangle at it's bottom. In addition, the rectangle can slowly move upwards and downwards.

How can I draw the rectangle so that just the parts of the arrows are visible that are in the rectangle?

For the moment, my rectangle looks like this:
[Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW2nL.jpg)

But it should look like this:
[Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzdZG.jpg)

Comment: Can you use `imgur.com` to host pictrures instead of `Dropbox`?

Comment: OK. I uploaded the pictures on imgur.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Draw all to [RenderTarget2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434402.aspx), and then draw it to game window.
2. Use [Clipping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/clipping-a-spritebatch-draw-in-xna) (for [XNA 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.scissorrectangle%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx))

Fisrt way will be better if you want move result image with all renderet on it.